# Can't login in the view Django

Tags: django, authentication

i can't create view for login. I try to login as created superuser, but i can't.
I tried create user via admin panel, but i can't login too as that user.

login_view function:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            print('successful')
        else:
            print('failed')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

login.html:

```
<body>
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  <p>You are logged</p>
  {% else %}
  <form class="w-50 mx-auto" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
  </form>
  {% endif %}
</body>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message, or is it printing `failed` in the terminal?

Comment: it prints failed

Comment: Are you using a custom user model by any chance?

Comment: I see you use an email for your login. Have you implemented the proper backend for that since it's not the default way of logging in?

Comment: @abdul-aziz-barkat I haven't created a new User model

Comment: @frédéric-perron what data I should use for login?

Comment: You should use the username to login. If you want to use the email, you can read a bit more about how to do this in the django docs. However, I would recommend trying with the username first to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @frédéric-perron, i tried via email I changed it to `authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`. And it doesn't work(without raising error)

Comment: But have you changed your input name in HTML to username too ?

Comment: It turns out not. You need to put the input type on the username too. Thank you, Frederic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` tag type should be `username`. And auth request should be like this `authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`